# Google chrome sending tons of ajax requests out of control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that fires via javascript:

```
$("#email_receipt").click(function()
{
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function()
    {
        show_feedback('success', <?php echo
        json_encode(lang('common_receipt_sent')); ?>, <?php echo
        json_encode(lang('common_success')); ?>);
    });

    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<?php echo anchor('sales/email_receipt/'.$sale_id_raw, lang('common_email_receipt'), array('id' => 'email_receipt','class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg hidden-print'));>
```

The problem I am running across (happened twice; one with a similar pattern). is that a valid user (not malicious) started sending requests at an alarming rate (10-30 a second). Is there a reason this would happen?

Comment: This might be a stupid question but someone has to do it right? Maybe multiple clicks to your element?

Comment: your user click link 10-30 times a second.

Comment: Perhaps disable the link when clicked, and re-enable when the call completes to avoid this scenario. Or use a flag/timer if concurrent calls are allowed/expected.

Comment: Simply disable the event emitter (button in your case) after it was clicked, and once the response comes back enable it again. There could be many different scenario why is that happening... it could be even faulty mouse, the button on the mouse.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic Could you share how this could happen? Could a browser allow a click even to happen that much because of a faulty mouse?

Comment: Faulty mouse is just an example of how various things can influence that button. It just o ures to me there is a possibity that the Browser is firing those requests. There was a similar question here on SO. I cant find it now

Comment: And yes, if the switch in the mouse is faulty, it can send unwanted clicks :)

Comment: Is the a way to apply behavior to all buttons without finding every event handler and add enable/disable function when clicking?